# Modifying to Google Chrome

Tags: vba

I have a code that works fine. The thing is it opens Internet Explorer for results. I want the results in Google Chrome. Modification would be helpful.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetResults(r As Range)
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim frm As Object
    Dim srch As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://www.google.com"
    Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set frm = IE.Document.forms("f")
    Set srch = frm.Document.all("q")
    srch.Value = r.Value
    frm.submit
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually the code opens IE not just for results but for the whole process of Google search request automation. Chrome doesn't allow automation such way, you should take a look at Selenium. And in this particular case just execute the line of code: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "chrome.exe ""https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(1, 1) & """", 1, True`, note it might be necessary to specify the full path to `chrome.exe` for your PC, so the code will look like `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" ""https:...`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be something similar written for [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic) vba wrapper. After installing selenium you need to go tools > references > add reference to selenium type library.

This is literally written to follow what you have written. You may wish to consider targeting by id not name, also, whether you want a function to return something from the results specifically.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = [A1]    '<== you really want a test that a single cell is passed or you will end up with an array later
    GetResults r 
End Sub

Public Sub GetResults(ByVal r As Range)
    Dim d As WebDriver, frm As Object, srch As Object
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "http://www.google.com"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        Set frm = .FindElementByName("f")
        Set srch = frm.FindElementByName("q")
        srch.SendKeys r.Value
        frm.submit
        Stop                                     '<=Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```